# JPA and how to search for user

Tags: java, jpa, derby

Ii am starting to learn `JPA` and how to use it so sorry if this is a simple question I am just starting out on this !

I have followed the `Netbeans tutorial` to create a simple **CRUD** application.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tql4COiN5T0

is the link to the tutorial

I have an entity, `jsfClasses`, `jsfClassses.util` source packages as well as an `AbstractFacade` and `userdetailsFacade`.

I have a succesful CRUD application which all works fine but I am looking to increase the functionality of it.

Is there any examples or tutorials available to show me how could I adapt this to search the database for a username containing a set string for example.

Thanks, sorry if its a poor question but I am just starting out on this topic area.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like following:

```
String userName = "admin";

public YourEntity getUserByUsername(String userName) {
    YourEntity yourEntity = new YourEntity();
    try {
        String jpql = "SELECT y FROM YourEntity y WHERE y.username =:username";
        Query query =em.createQuery(jpql);
        qquery.setParameter("username",userName);
        yourEntity=query.getSingleResult();
        return yourEntity;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now you can get `entityObject` from `getUserByUsername(...)` method. Which will return only associated username information.